# Custom 404 Page issue in sub folders

Tags: html, http, http-status-code-404

I am noticing my 404 page works fine when the wrong address is requesting something on the root level  `www.mywebsite.com/nopage.html` . But if I am going to a subpage that is not there then my 404 does not show correctly  `www.mywebsite.com/admin/nopage.html` . Is the only way to do this is set absolute paths to all the style sheets, links and images in your 404?

this is my http.conf entry:

```
ServerName www.mywebsite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/currentsite
ErrorDocument 404 /404error.php
<Directory /var/www/currentsite>
  Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks +Includes
  AllowOverride all
 Allow from all
 Order allow,deny
</Directory>
```

Is there a way to send the browser to the 404 page verse calling the 404 down to where ever the user has ended up at?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `<base href="http://www.mywebsite.com">` to the `head` tag of your error page to make all relative urls resolve relative to `www.mywebsite.com` (instead of `www.mywebsite.com/admin`). I'm assuming that your error page is dynamically generated anyway, so if this error page needs to work on multiple domain names, it shouldn't be hard to add the correct domain name to the page on the server.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add `http://` to the url. Without it, the browser would probably try to load urls relative to `http://www.mywebsite.com/the/url/that/was/not/found/www.mywebsite.com`, instead of just `http://www.mywebsite.com`, which is likely not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

In your .htaccess file use complete URL address for your 
error page path

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.yourdomain.com/404.html

Good Luck!

Answer (score -1):

Just adding some information to Kianoush's answer.

Add the redirect to one 404-Page to all of your `.htaccess` files: (root and if every subfolder have an own `.htaccess`, then there as well)

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.yourdomain.com/404.html

Further the paths in your 404-Page must be completed:

- wrong: `href="../css/style.css"`
- right: `href="https://www.yourdomain.com/css/style.css"`

This must be added for each file, image, etc.. in your 404-Page.

Comment: Sometimes I find answers in 10, 15 or 20 years old posts. 
Was just trying to be helpful.